# How does pulling backwards on the pedals cause the bike to move backwards?

Tags: forces, angular-momentum, free-body-diagram

I saw this video by George Hart recently:
https://www.simonsfoundation.org/2014/03/20/mathematical-impressions-the-bicycle-pulling-puzzle/

Hart attached a string to the pedal while it was on the bottom position and pulled on it. The bike then started to move backwards. The explanation was that given a forward moving bike, the motion of the pedal forms a trochoid with no backwards motion. Thus a backwards force always goes *against* the motion of the pedal observed when the bike is going forward, and thus the bike goes backwards.

[image]

*(The red line is the motion of the pedal, the red arrow is the force of the string on the pedal, and the blue arrow is the component of the force along the path of the pedal)*

However, as seen in the video, when the bike starts going forward the pedal starts to move counterclockwise. I'm assuming this happens because the tires move the chain which in turn moves the pedal.

Basically my confusion comes from the fact that I'm not sure what the free-body diagram of this setup looks like. What are all the relevant forces at work? Why is the pull on the pedal not a torque that rotates the pedals clockwise? How does the force of the string move the bike backwards through the pedal/chain/tire system to cause the pedal to accelerate in the direction away from the force?

Comment: In case you haven't seen it yet, [Veritasium discusses this problem here](https://youtu.be/72DCj3BztG4?t=346).

Comment: @Philip that's actually what I originally saw! However Hart's video goes more in depth I think. But in any case, neither video really addresses the confusions I have :(